# Consulta sql que me muestre todos los clientes y los que no compraron en cierta fecha reemplazar por null

Tags: sql, servidor

¿Cómo puedo mostrar todos los clientes y si no compraron en esa fecha, cambiarlos por null?

Adjunto consulta que me muestra solo los clientes que compraron el 12 de febrero de 2016

```
SELECT clienteid ,productoid , fechaorden 
FROM Ventas.Ordenes INNER JOIN Ventas.DetallesOrden
ON Ordenes.ordenid = DetallesOrden.ordenid
Where fechaorden  ='2016-02-12';
```

Comment: Quieres ver la tabla o modificarla? Con una select sólo puedes ver.

Answer (score 1):

Lo estás planteando al revés. Realiza una `UPDATE` y pon `null` a todos los que no compraron en esa fecha:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET column1 = null
WHERE fechaorden NOT '2016-02-12';
```

Ahora ya puedes realizar tu select para ver quienes compraron en esa fecha y el resto estará `null`.

Comment: Pero no quiero modificvar los datos , solo mediante la consulta me muestre los usuarios que no compraron y dejarlos null

Comment: Con qué fin quieres realizar eso? Cuándo vas a querer ver los clientes que no han comprado en una fecha concreta como null?

Comment: es un ejercicio de la universidad , y tengo que realizar una consulta y hacer que me muestre los datos de esa manera

Answer (score 0):

És muy probable que te haga falta hacer el join con clientes, probablemente tienes que añadir un left o right join con clientes o cambiar el innerjoin por un leftjoin y forzar que salgan todos los clientes, para decir que la fecha puede ser la fecha o null puedes usar `coalesce()`

https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2014/07/16/manipulando-valores-nulos-con-coalesce-y-lnnvl

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

De tal manera que `coalesce(fechaorden, null)` devolvera o la fecha de la orden o `null`.

Aquí un ejemplo parecido

```
SELECT md.new_name,md.new_motivodecisionid,
  coalesce(rm.new_relacionmotivosid,'-1') as new_relacionmotivosid,
  rm.new_motivoeleccion, rm.new_motivorenuncia
FROM new_motivodecision md 
  left join new_relacionmotivos rm on rm.new_motivodecisionid = md.new_motivodecisionid
    and rm.new_opportunityid = 'xxx-xxx-xxx' Where md.statecode = 0
```

Aquí estoy cogiendo todos los motivos de decisión tengan o no tengan una relacion con la entidad Oportunity, con `coalesce()` si la entidad `new_relacionmotivos` no contiene un `new_motivoeleccionid` junto a `Oportunityid` marca la `new_relacionmotivosid` como `'-1'`, en tu caso sería `null`

Como no sé que estructura de datos tienes un posible ejemplo del caso que me comentas sería el siguiente

```
SELECT clienteid ,productoid , coalesce(fechaorden, null)  
FROM Ventas.Ordenes INNER JOIN Ventas.DetallesOrden
ON Ordenes.ordenid = DetallesOrden.ordenid 
left join Ventas.Clientes on Ordenes.clienteid = Clientes.clienteid
Where fechaorden  ='2016-02-12';
```

o

```
SELECT clienteid ,productoid , coalesce(fechaorden, null)  
FROM Ventas.Ordenes INNER JOIN Ventas.DetallesOrden
ON Ordenes.ordenid = DetallesOrden.ordenid
Where fechaorden  ='2016-02-12';
```